# Create Custom shapes in WPF(Preferably using Microsoft Expression Blend 4)

Tags: wpf

i wanted to know how could we draw custom shapes in wpf (may be using expression blend4), without using pen feature of expression blend4. i wanted to draw the below mentioned button such as irregular shaped buttons .

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) object to draw irregular shapes

For example,

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" Data="M 10 100 L 100 100 L 100 50 Z" />
```

Will start at 10,100, draw a line to 100,100, then another line to 100,50, then close the path by drawing a line back to the starting point.

[image: Example]

You can also use lower-case letters to use relative positions. For example,

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" Data="M 10 100 l 90 0 l 0 -50 Z" />
```

Would draw the same shape, but use relative paths. It will start at 10,100, draw a line going +90 along the x, and 0 along the y, then another line going 0 along the x and -50 along the y.

A shorter version of the same line would be

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" Data="M 10 100 h 90 v -50 Z" />
```

which starts at 10,100, goes horizontal 90, then vertically -50

One resource I often use when building a Path is [this site](http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/), which lists the commands for the "geometry mini-language"

Of course, you can also build your Path object in full XAML if you prefer:

```
<Path Stroke="Blue">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100" IsClosed="True">
                <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                <LineSegment Point="100,50" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```